# hard indefinite integral with unreal solution

Tags: definite-integrals

Can someone give me an idea on how I should solve this?

> $$\int \frac{1}{2 \sin{\left (x \right )} + 5 \cos{\left (x \right )}}\, dx$$

I tried to enter a replacement, but I'm not sure how to continue. Here's the [exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Crr1.jpg).

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHQ6F.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, choose a better title to your question.

Comment: Why are you jumping all over the place? It was first an indefinite, then definite, now again an indefinite integral...

Comment: @AndrewLi. Have you  seen this:http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0489099/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1. TaumCkBep is a Jumper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

Use substitution: $\:t=\tan \dfrac x2,\quad \mathrm dt=\frac12(1+t^2)\,\mathrm dx$, and the trigonometric formulæ: 
$$\sin x = \frac{2t}{1+t^2},\qquad \cos x = \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much, I made it!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Take $\theta$ such that $\cos\theta=\frac2{\sqrt{29}}$ and that $\sin\theta=\frac5{\sqrt{29}}$. Then$$\frac1{2\sin(x)+5\cos(x)}=\frac1{\sqrt{29}\sin(x+\theta)}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$2\sin x+5\cos x=\sqrt{2^2+5^2}\cos\left(x-\arccos\dfrac5{\sqrt29}\right)$$

Now use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_the_secant_function)